# Autoscroll goes too far in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am testing a bootstrap webpage, auto scroll works on desktop but scrolls to far on mobile and makes my `<h2>` disappear and leave only the `<p>` tags visible.

Why does this scroll down not scroll to the beginning of the section?

Can anybody help me out? Many thanks

Menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
    <li class="hidden">
        <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Over</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#Teams">Teams</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sponsoren">Sponsoren</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>                
</ul>
```

Section:

```
<section id="about" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".2s "> 
            <h2>test</h2>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.content-section{}
```

js:

```
// jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
function collapseNavbar() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
}

$(window).scroll(collapseNavbar);
$(document).ready(collapseNavbar);

// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: declare mobile classes in `<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2...`> something like `col-sm-12` may work? You're only declaring a `col-lg` for large screens, nothing for smaller screen